# Modal image gallery with database-driven dynamic results

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53462883/setting-up-modal-images-with-dynamic-image-gallery-using-ajax) question awhile back and didn't get any hits, so I thought I'd try again while being a bit more general and see if I get any results.

The concepts of how a static modal page makes sense to me. I can follow along in the [W3 Schools tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp) easily, and it makes a lot of sense- Add a modal section in your HTML, grab the image with JavaScript and write a function to change the appearance of the page when an image is clicked on with some CSS. Simple enough.

Same goes for if you have a few different images. It gets a bit repetitive, but you can just add different IDs for each image and do the same thing with a series of JavaScript getElementById()s. No problem.

But what if you're working with an image page with hundreds of images? And what if you're using Ajax to dynamically filter down to certain types of images (driven by database interaction). I use PHP to do my interaction with the database and it's easy enough to write a for loop to add a unique ID to each image that appears. But how do I add the modal functionality given that there are hundreds of different IDs to grab, especially when you won't know what images are on a page at a certain time?

Theoretically you *could* write hundreds of different JavaScript getElementById()s to handle all possible cases. But that's quite tedious and not efficient at all. I'd be shocked if there wasn't a better way to do it, but I haven't stumbled across the answer yet. Is there a way to say "look for a click on any of these images, but only show the modal display for the specific image you clicked on"?

Comment: yep...give all the elements the same CSS class. Then handle a click event on that class. When the callback runs, `this` will be the specific element which was actually clicked.

Comment: To clarify what @ADyson said, you can use `document.querySelectorAll("img.yourModalClass")` to get a list of every image on the page you want to add a click handler to. Then you can do something with them like `addEventListener("click", function() {});`.

Comment: For some reason it never occurred to me to use classes to listen for clicks. Seems obvious now. Question on the second part, though, since `this` can be confusing- Say I have `<div class=modal><img src=...></div>`, in that case `this` will select the full div? Am I able to do something like `this.img` to access the image?

Comment: if the click event was handled on the div, then the div will be `this`. It depends what you attached the event to. And yes you can find elements within other elements - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector

Comment: Nice. That makes my solution pretty simple after all. Thank you